# "/ask question" in the site header should be changed to "/ ask question"

Tags: bug, design

All the links in the navigation bar have a space in-between the `/` and the text except for "ask question." This happens both on main and on meta, and should probably be fixed at some point.

Comment: +1 thanks, now I can't look at it without noticing. ._.

Comment: @Junaga innit awful?

Comment: I think the others should be changed to conform with the Unix convention of no spaces at the beginning of directory names `/etc`...

Comment: @jasonwryan thats actually even better

Comment: I think this is new (and probably inadvertent); I dug up a screenshot from a couple months ago where there were [no spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvOJQ.png)

Comment: In addition, the typeface used in the "U&L" logo has bad [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) between "U" and "n" in "Unix". I'll just leave this here...

Answer (score 16):

Just because an alternate solution was offered in the comments, here it is for voting purposes:

> I think the others should be changed to conform with the Unix
> convention of no spaces at the beginning of directory names
> /etc...
>
> jasonwryan

Comment: When is this going to get implemented?  :)

Comment: Is there any progress on this?

Answer (score -4):

For voting purposes, the original proposal:

> All the links in the navigation bar have a space in-between the / and
> the text
>
> strugee